# i cant view nearby wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless, internet

So I just installed Lubuntu and I can't seem to view nearby wifi connections. It just shows the `+`, `-`, and the `settings` buttons, but only the `+` button is clickable. When I do click it, it just brings me into this configuaration page where I have to enter everything: `ssid`, `bssid`, `device`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

In Right bottom click on the wifi signal bar, it will show nearby wifi networks.

or

Type

nmcli dev wifi
or
nmcli -f ALL dev wifi

in  qterminal to get more details on wifi networks around